# How to recompile the react native node dependency?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native android component as an npm dependency to my react native project. It is autolinked during react-native run-android. I have made changes to the dependency java files(node_modules/dependency/android/com/z/y/x/Foo.java). How to recompile the project inorder to get the changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your project folder `cd android && ./gradlew clean`. Note that what you doing should only be used for prototyping, as your changes in `node_modules` are not going into version control system and are also being erased on `npm install`